# Всё пропало! Иероглифы вместо текста

Tags: дефект, блок-кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причём когда я открыл вопрос, там был пустой блок кода. После обновления страницы - появилось это:

Ссылка на вопрос: [Персонаж не появляется на нужном месте Unity 3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1291984/184217)

Ответ в теме, кстати, пустой.

---

Update.
Уже нормально отображается.

В этом вопросе: [Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "DB" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1291775/184217) - тоже был пустой блок кода. После рефреша страницы код появился. Причём у вопроса нет правок.

Comment: Может ли это быть связано с непрогрузкой css или чего-то стороннего, используемого для форматирования кода?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ - несколько раз мне попадались сообщения с пустыми блоками кода. Я входил в режим редактирования, чтобы проверить: там были лишь пробельные символы. То есть сам текст сообщения был изменён.